# Linux Mint draining power, VGA errors

Tags: linux, laptop, linux-mint, vga, overheating

I have a Dell laptop, with Core i7 processor, radeon r7 dedicated vga.
In windows, everything is fine, battery can hold up to 7 hours (im amazed).
In Linux (which i must use for specific jobs) the laptop is heating up, everything feels like software rendered (from lagging youtube to lagging scrolling in chromium, and other programs)
I usually use a second screen (with HDMI connection)
The system is up to date.

The hotkeys, like brightness (Fn+f11, and such) are seems to work (OSD icon shows that im changing brightness, for example) but the brightnerss actually doesn't change.
When i mess with the screen settings (like turning off one of the screens) the video rendering collapse, flickering lines and picture everywhere, etc.

Please, anybody have any suggestions?